# White font when rendering kable object through R notebook

Tags: html, r, colors, rstudio, kable

This is less of asking for code solution, but more of requesting an explanation of the unexpected code behavior.
When I use `kable_styling` on console, the table is displayed as expected: white background, black font.

However, when I run it within Rmd, the resulting table is white background and white font, that can only be seen if you highlight it.

[image: white font behavior]

[image: if I highlight them]

I fixed this by simply adding `table.attr = "style = \"color: black;\""`, but can someone chime in why this strange behavior occur?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be that the RStudio theme you chose (under tools, global options, appearances) applies the theme (dark w/ white letters) to everything in the viewer pane, including your rendered table. If you switch the theme to something with darker letters, the output in the viewer pane will follow.

It's also addressed here: https://community.rstudio.com/t/using-dark-theme-with-preview/1891